# Xcode int variable holding multiple values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, int, nstimer

In my "xcode" timer project, I have a int variable named "overall". When I first set up my timer the overall variable is set to the amount of seconds wanted for the timer. I then have an `NSTimer` taking a second of the variable every second.

```
overall = (timerMin * 60) + (timerHour * 60 * 60) + timer;
[self setTimer];

When i first set the variable
```

If the app enters the background I record the date and then the date of when it enters the foreground. I then find out the difference of the two dates and take it away from the overall variable. And recall the `NSTimer`.

```
[Countdown invalidate];
Countdown = nil;

overallBackground = [saveOverall integerForKey:overall_save];
int newOverall = (int)overallBackground - secondsInBackground;
overall = newOverall;

[self setTimer];

When i set it after re-entering the app from background
```

The problem I have is that even though I have been into the background and reset the overall variable when the Timer was restarted the overall variable number from before was still there but the variable was also storing the new number!

```
2014-05-11 16:48:18.759 Timer[836:60b] overall:3595 - Old number
2014-05-11 16:48:19.044 Timer[836:60b] overall:3591 - New number
2014-05-11 16:48:19.759 Timer[836:60b] overall:3594 - Old number
2014-05-11 16:48:20.044 Timer[836:60b] overall:3590 - New number

    NSLog(@"overall:%d", overall);


    overall = overall - 1;
    [saveOverall setInteger:overall forKey:overall_save];
    [saveOverall synchronize];


    hours = overall / 3600;
    minutes = overall - (hours * 3600);
    minCon = minutes / 60;
    seconds = minutes - (minCon * 60);
```

From the log above you can see what I mean. I am printing the exact same variable to the log, just so you know.

My question is why is this happening? And how do I stop it?

Comment: What code? You have not posted any code.  That is just some log output. Please add your relevant code.

Comment: There you go I have added the code when i first set the variable and when i re-set it after entering from the background

Comment: But you haven't added the code where overall is declared nor where the NSLog statements are nor the context for where the posted code is located nor where saveOverall is getting its value from. Its almost certainly just a logic error and if you step through it line by line in Xcode you will see what's going on.

Comment: But still how is it possible for one variable to contain two numbers?

Comment: It isn't possible. You just think it is based on what you are seeing from the log statements. It must be a bug, you just haven't found the cause yet. At least post the log statements here.

Comment: Please study the "C" language with particular attention to how variables are maintained in memory.

Comment: I have posted it up ! Also I have just found out that even though i stop the timer meaning the void want be called anymore the new overall part of the variable continues to print out in the log! I have searched my whole project thinking i had asked it to print somewhere else but i haven't !

Comment: Simplify the project to the least amount of code that still produces the problem. Then you should be able to see where the error is. Also, by convention variables start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: There still isn't enough code displayed here for us to debug it, you'll have to post more or do as Zaph suggests (duplicate your project then start chopping bits away).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/G5f864SD here is my ViewController.m and .h if you could have a look

Comment: There's too much there to digest quickly and I have to go offline for a few hours. However I am left puzzled by your description saying you are doing stuff when the app enters the background. In the code posted there is nothing that I saw triggered on background/foreground moves unless I missed it i.e. no monitoring for applicationDiEnterBackground etc.

Comment: Thanks guys I went through my program and changed some code and i started working not really sure how or why but it is working so.